# USB mouse lag with XFCE on Ubuntu 18.04, Xorg display

Tags: usb, mouse, xfce

I upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, and disabled Wayland and enabled the Xorg display.  I use the xfce desktop on a Lenovo T430s.  After a few seconds of inactivity, my Logitech USB mouse is unresponsive until I move it around for a couple of seconds and/or depress a button or the center wheel.  The problem is "fixed" by unplugging and re-plugging in the USB dongle ... until the next reboot.

- The problem does *not* happen with the default ubuntu desktop.
- The problem does *not* depend on which USB port the dongle is plugged
  in to.
- The same behavior occurs for two different Logitech mouse/dongle
  pairs.
- I never had this issue using xfce with ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I am spitballing here because I am not 100% sure what your issue is.  I use Xfce4 and I won't go to any other DE.  Maybe use Compton http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/ instead of xfwm4 as the compositor.  In the instructions, just install compton without adding any repositories `sudo apt install compton` but the rest of the instructions are still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem, which is not likely to affect anyone else in the universe, but here's the solution anyway.  As part of an autostart script for Xfce, I was using powertop to make power-saving adjustments (powertop --auto-tune). This included power management for the USB Logitech receiver, which caused the USB mouse to fall asleep after a few seconds of inactivity.

I replaced my powertop command with an excellent script (https://askubuntu.com/a/1026527/824514) that autotunes powertop but subsequently disables power management for USB devices using the Human Interface Device driver.

I don't know why I didn't have this problem in ubuntu 16.04, nor do I care to think about it.

Thanks to Ric Klaren for the script, and to Chris Pavlovich at Oregon State University for helping me identify the problem.