# Ubuntu Studio * how to get WiFi & display working with stock (generic) kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel, 18.04, amd-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 and I experience some a massive mouse lag after a while [(this question)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067616/18-04-mouse-lag-irq-disabled) This happens with 4.15 lowlatency kernel Ubuntu Studio is shippped with. Since I ran out of ideas and wanted to try the generic kernel I installed 4.15.0-20 headers and image. I can boot, but I won't get full resolution on my screen and WiFi device is not available.

How come? Which extra packages do I need to install or remove in order to get this working?
In both of my last OSs Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu Studio 14.04 I had several generic, lowlatency & rt-preempt kernels installed, and switching between them never was an issue.

Devices:
RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
AMD Radeon HD 6620G graphics adapter (default driver, only LVDS screen used)

**Edit**
I tried all generic kernels up to 4.15.0-32 to no avail..

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. After the `$` prompt type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Your kernel should be automatically updated to the most recent version `4.15.0-32` I believe.

If you see messages the new kernel is installed, you can activate it by rebooting so type:

```
sudo reboot
```

If you don't get the most recent kernel installed post a comment below.

---

**NOTE:** I've had bad luck with the `4.15` kernel chain on my laptop (Skylake), eg won't suspend, occasional keyboard 5-10 second freeze and won't suspend with three monitors. So I'm using `4.13` kernel chain instead.

Comment: That apt/apt-get move wouldn't work for me. I tried pretty much all 4.15 kernels from the official repo (via Synaptic), they suffer the same bug. And the repos don't offer 4.16 kernels, that's why a hint to kernels source might help others.

Comment: @ronso0 Sorry I'm confused by `apt move` or `apt-get move` I don't know anything about those two commands... Some kernels are broken for `apt remove` and `apt-get remove` for the last few months but a fix is in for that. (apparently). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: "move" refers to some kind of `apt`/`apt-get` "action" like `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

I got WiFi and graphics working with 4.**16**.0-041600-generic headers & image from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

For some reason (I don't have time to investigate) 4.15.0-x-**generic** has problems with realtek and amd gpu drivers on my machine(1), whereas 4.15.0-x-**lowlatency** works out of-the-box

(1) Thinkpad Edge 525 12003NG