# Script not working correctly (powertop)

Tags: scripts

I am trying to improve my laptop's energy consumption by using `powertop` and a script to change the settings after booting.The script I made is based on the answer of Ric Klaren under this post: [`powertop --auto-tune` without messing with USB and touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678779/powertop-auto-tune-without-messing-with-usb-and-touchpad)

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
powertop --auto-tune
HIDDEVICES=3-1
for i in ; do
  echo -n "Enabling " | cat - /sys/bus/usb/devices//product
  echo 'on' > /sys/bus/usb/devices//power/control
done
```

Somehow it does not work as intended and enables every option, as well as those concerning my USB mouse.
Here's the output, if I run the script:

```
modprobe cpufreq_stats failedLoaded 127 prior measurements  
RAPL device for cpu 0  
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d  
RAPL device for cpu 0  
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d  
Devfreq not enabled  
glob returned GLOB_ABORTED  
To show power estimates do 221 measurement(s) connected to battery only  
Leaving PowerTOP
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your script as given won't do anything because the loop is empty, so it can't possibly show the output you say it does.

Comment: You removed all the `$VARIABLES` from the script. Try putting them back!